# Primefaces exporter doesn't work inside c:forEach

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to create tables with a List < List < Params > >. When I use < ui:repeat >, the Primefaces exporter works fine, but, the panelGrid don't, as expected. And, when I use c:forEach, the panelGrid works, but, the Primefaces exporter don't. 
How can I use ui:repeat and the panelGrid? Or c:forEach with Primefaces exporter? Can Anyone help me? Thanks.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="myPanelGrid">
<c:forEach varStatus="status_loop" items="#{ManagedBean.report}" var="params">
    <h:form id="form_tbl_#{status_loop.index}">
        <p:panel id="myPanel_#{status_loop.index}" > 
                <p:dataTable id="tbl_ativ_#{status_loop.index}"
                             value="#{params}"
                             var="p"
                             scrollHeight="80"
                             scrollable="true">
                    <p:column headerText="Name" >
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{p.name}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <h:commandLink id="cmd_link" class="ui-right">
                            <p:graphicImage library="default" name="img/excel.png" width="24"/>
                            <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl_ativ_#{status_loop.index}" fileName="excel_report" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
  </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: I want to use ui:repeat OR the c:forEach, with the panelGrid with 2 columns and the Primefaces exporter. Thanks for reply.